# Hindi tweets datasets freely available

Tags: data-request

I am working on macaronic language analysis. I need a dataset of hindi tweets or other devnagri languages. Could someone send me the datasets or the links where I can find them?

Comment: Can you use Twitter's search function and/or write a small program that grabs tweets in the appropriate language in real time?

Answer (score 1):

The Streaming APIs give developers low latency access to Twitter’s global stream of Tweet data. A proper implementation of a streaming client will be pushed messages indicating Tweets and other events have occurred, without any of the overhead associated with polling a REST endpoint.

If your intention is to conduct singular searches, read user profile information, or post Tweets, consider using the REST APIs instead.

Please refer this link: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview